# Java boolean method: unreachable statement

Tags: java, arrays, methods, boolean

I want to check if there are no elements in an array.

```
private Player[] players = new Player[maxPlayers];

public boolean activePlayer(){
    for(int i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
        if(players[i] != null) {
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

ItelliJ marks `break;` red with the message `unreachable statement`. What does this mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: because nothing in that block after `return true;` will be executed

Comment: because of the `return`

Comment: the break statement comes after the return statement. return means you exit the method. remove the break and it will compile

Comment: return statement immediately RETURNS from method, so break is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement right before the `break` will immediately end the method, so the `break` will never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

We use `return` to *return a value* back to the calling method, so therefore once control goes inside the `if` block the value `true` is returned to the calling method hence the `break` will never be reached.

To put it simply, `return` ends the execution of the current method and *returns a value back* to the *caller*.

Answer (score 0):

Think through the serial behavior of the program, one line at a time. If it makes it past the conditional statements, it will hit the return statement. In Java, [`return` terminates a function, *returning* control to the calling function and potentially *returning* a value as well](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html). The break line will never be touched!

This might help you understand the flow of control in a Java program: http://www.dickbaldwin.com/java/Java026.htm

If you add more information about what you would like the program to do/ what you expect from the break statement, we'd be happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

in simple terms, the if the first if condition is true then it will  only goto "return true;" and exit... if it does not go into the If block then it will continue to loop through and end at "return false;" So yes intelliJ is right. it should never come to the "break;"

the return true; will actually do the break for you and you don't need to do it explicitly and it will return to where ever you are calling the function "activePlayers()"

If you explain why you are adding a break, we may be able to help you further

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Java, returning a value in a function will, in order,:
1. stop executing the code inside of the function
2. return the value in the function

ItelliJ is a very snappy and "intelligent" code checker that tells you when something is wrong or buggy.
It is giving you the error, "unreachable statement" because the "break" statement never gets executed because when you return "true"... (look back at the first part of the answer)... the break statement never gets executed.

So it is therefore an "unreachable" statement that will never be executed in any case whatsoever.